# Creating a vector of objects

Tags: c++

```
vector <Population> obj;

int num_of_cities = 0;

cout<<"Enter the number of cities"<<endl;
cin>>num_of_cities;

for( int x = 0; x < num_of_cities ; x++)
{
    cout<<"Enter population for city #"<< x + 1 <<endl;
    cin>>populate;
    obj[x].setPopulation(populate);
.....
```

Im trying to make a vector of objects. Basically the user will input the amount of cities and the program should create an object for each city. That way information on each city can be entered. I believe there is a problem with the syntax because once I put a value for populate, the program crashes. Any one can help ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `obj` is a `vector` with no content, so `obj[x]` is accessing out of bounds. Generally you would `push_back` a `Population` object or `resize` to make the `vector` have that many elements (which would be default constructed) before using array indexing.

Comment: *"I'm trying to make a vector of objects.*" - In C++, every vector is a vector of objects, because in C++, even instances of primitive types are called "objects". The correct wording would be "a vector of objects of custom type".

Comment: Thanks I always get confused with properly wording a couple things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is the problem:

```
obj[x].setPopulation(populate);
```

You are trying to access the object at index `x` but your `vector` is actually **empty**.

To solve this, there is 2 solutions:

- You should create a `Population` object and `push_back` to your `vector` at each loop iteration

Example:

```
//...    
for( int x = 0; x < num_of_cities ; x++)
{
    cout<<"Enter population for city #"<< x + 1 <<endl;
    cin>>populate;
    Population pop;
    pop.setPopulation(populate)
    obj.push_back(pop);
}
//...
```

- Or you initialize your `vector` with a size only when you know the number of cities: `vector <Population> obj (num_of_cities);`

Example:

```
//...
cin>>num_of_cities;
vector <Population> obj (num_of_cities); // move your vector declaration here
for( int x = 0; x < num_of_cities ; x++)
//...
```

Comment: First example have an extra copy-construction and hurt performance. Second assumes there is a default constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, this is the downside of the first solution

Comment: Yet there is an elgant solutition free from the drawbacks of both.

Comment: Thanks ! Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

```
obj[x].setPopulation(populate);
```

here you are trying to access an element which is out-of-bound, since the vector `obj` has no content yet.

A way to make this work would be to call

```
obj.resize(num_of_cities)
```

before the for loop.
A more general approach (which would work if you do not know beforehand how many elements you will have, but which is slower in this case), would be creating a `Population` object, and then pushing it to the vector:

```
Population p;
p.setPopulation(populate);
obj.push_back(p);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following code will let you make a vector of city objects that you can then populate with meaningful data. First, you need to define a City class that can set and get the various data items. The code will compile and run but it is a limited version of what you might want to accomplish.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class City {
public:
    City() {}
    ~City() {}
    void setPopulation(int& pop) { m_pop = pop; }
    int getPopulation() const { return m_pop; }
    void setName(const string& name) { m_name = name; }
    string getName() const { return m_name; }
private:
    string m_name{ "" };
    int m_pop{ 0 };
};

vector<City> cities(0);

int num_of_cities = 0;

int main() {

    do {
        cout << "Enter number of cities: ";
        cin >> num_of_cities;
    } while (num_of_cities < 1);

    cities.resize(num_of_cities);

    int val{ 0 };
    string nam{ "" };
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Enter name of city: ";
        cin >> nam;
        cities[i].setName(nam);
        cout << "Enter population for city: ";
        cin >> val;
        cities[i].setPopulation(val);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While currently available answers correctly identify the source of the problem at hand - access to empty vector - they fail to set the right example of using the vector in a given scenario. They either suggest a push_back of pre-constructed object - thus calling a copy-construcor unnecessarily - or demand a presence of default constructor, with a side effect of exra assignment.

The most elegant solution would be following:

Make sure your Population has a constructor which accepts population size and sets internal member accordingly (likely to be const int):

```
Population::Population(int habitants) : habitants(habitants) { }
```

Than, use `emplace_back` to insert an object without calling any other constructors:

```
obj.emplace_back(populate);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate the help